# $\int_c -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy $ for $c(t) = (cost, sint)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The above question I suggested, the answer is clearly $2\pi$. But I tried different way like the below.

$F = (-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$ is conservative on region $D$. To say $F$ be conservative, We need the condition "open connected, $D$". So I took the somewhere open connected, $D$ which is $(0,0)\not\in D$ and $C\subset  D$.

On $D$, there exists potential fucntion, $\phi = tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ $s.t.$ $(\phi_x,\phi_y) = F$

So $\int_c -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} dx +  \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy = \phi(C(\pi)) - \phi(C(0)) =0$

What is wrong in my solution? Do we need more conditions to guarantee the existence of the potential function? Or If exists, Should the potential function be continuous on Curve?

Comment: Is your alleged potential function $C^1$ everywhere on $C$?

Comment: No. It is not continuous on x=0. So it is not $C^1$ on D. Then we can't apply gradient theorem. Thanks for your hint. I got it right now. :)